# discord.py-message-components 'message.channel.send()' broken in dms

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

discord.py-message-components package

```
await message.channel.send(mem)
AttributeError: 'Object' object has no attribute 'send'
```

discord.py package

```
await message.channel.send(mem)
sends successfully
```

Note, sending commands and receiving output using `discord.py-message-components` works fine in server channels but breaks in dms.

Does anyone have a reason as to why this is and/or a solution?

Comment: this is most likely a bug in the lib you're using, try opening an issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little bit late but... yeah...

This is fixed for a longer time now. Just update to the newest developer version using

```py
# Linux/macOS
python3 -m pip install -U git+https://github.com/mccoderpy/discord.py-message-components.git@developer

# Windows
py -m pip install -U git+https://github.com/mccoderpy/discord.py-message-components.git@developer
```

Answer (score 0):

Well basically the class `Message` you can use it on events like

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message:discord.Message):
   await message.chnnael.send("Hello World")
```